# Verify a link in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, automation, selenium-webdriver

I'm having a web link which directs to the "/login.html" page. How can I verify whether the link works properly. I already have this :

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();    
driver.get("www.something.com/login.html");
String mesg = "Login Page";
Assert.assertEquals(mesg, driver.getTitle());
```

but I want a proper way to verify.

Comment: Is this way not proper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common solution is to identify an element or some text that exists on the expected page, and which doesn't exist in any content the user would see if something unexpected happened. Then just assert on the presence of that content.

For example (this code uses the WebDriver Python API, but the pattern applies to any language):

```
success_text = "Welcome, user foo!"
assert success_text in self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("p.welcome_msg").text
```

You can keep adding more assertions or keep it simple, depending on your preference.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and implement HTTP status response checker, currently it's [long-awaited feature](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=141) for a couple of years already.

It will look something like:

```
 HttpResponse response = new HttpRequestBuilder(HttpMethod.GET, linkUrl)
                    .execute(); 
//response assertion
```